# Is it possible to run Acquia Dev Destop without admin rights on Windows?

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

I would like to know if it is possible to run Acquia Dev Desktop without local Admin rights on Windows machine?

I requested admin right and was given for temporary period and installed the software and was able to run it. But can no longer Run Acquia Dev Desktop (after my admin rights expired). Launching the application just asks for admin credentials.

So how would I be able to run the software without getting elevated rights?

Comment: You are a web developer. You should be given an admin account.

Comment: @leymannx is right, being a developer without admin rights is not possible. Without being able to run sudo web development isn't really possible.

Comment: @Jdupal yes, but company only gives 48 hours admin rights to everyone after request. Would it work if i gain the temporary admin rights, and give my user account Full rights to "C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop" folder?

Comment: Maybe, but what if you need to install a php extenstion etc.

Comment: well, yes at that point have to request rights again. Any registry access Dev Desktop requires though? But why does it require Admin right to run the software though? one should be able to run without

Comment: This is not normal software, it is an old fashioned WAMP stack running services on the client OS. Use a VM or docker based dev environment, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/local-server-setup/docker-development-environments